# Spring Boot multiple configurations files with same names and same properties names

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties, configuration

I am trying to setup a Spring Boot monolithic app which should behave like a microservice and I have some issues to manage configurations (.properties). 
This is how I organized the project (`resources` folder) : 
[image: resources directory tree]

As you can see there are common properties files : `application.properties`,`application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` these properties should be shared by all sub-properties and they can eventually be overridden.

Each `service` has its own data source url and it also depending on the active profile : `H2` for `dev` and `MySQL` for `prod`.

Here an exemple of how I manage configurations :

Contents of common `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.config.additional-location=classpath:productservice/, classpath:userservice/,classpath:financeservice/, classpath:securityservice/ #I am not sure this works...
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none 
spring.jpa.properties.validation-mode=none
```

Contents of common `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/db
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
spring.datasource.username=sa # We override data source username and paswword
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Contents of common `application-prod.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Now for specific services :

**productservice :**

Content of `application.properties`:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:productservice/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.default-schema=productservicedb
spring.liquibase.check-change-log-location=true
```

Content of `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:productservicedb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS productservicedb;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Content of `application-prod.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productservicedb?useSSL=false
```

And for **userservice** I have :

Content of `application.properties` :

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:userservice/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.default-schema=userservice
spring.liquibase.check-change-log-location=true
```

Content of `application-dev.properties` :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:userservicedb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS userservicedb;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Content of `application-prod.properties` :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userservicedb
```

And so on ... for other services.

To configure each data source I proceed like this :

**productservice :**

1- Retrieve properties from environment :

```
@Configuration( "productServiceProperties" )
@Getter
@Setter
@PropertySource( value = { "classpath:productservice/application.properties",
  "classpath:productservice/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" } )
public class ProductServiceProperties {

   @Autowired//I want `Environment` to contain properties from common properties + files in @PropertySource above
   private Environment environment;

    // ========DATASOURCE PROPERTIES=========
   private String      datasourceDriverClass;
   private String      datasourceUsername;
   private String      dataSourcePassword;
   private String      dataSourceUrl;

   // ========LIQUIBASE PROPERTIES==========
   private String      liquibaseChangeLog;
   private String      liquibaseDefaultSchema;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      this.datasourceDriverClass = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.driver-class-name" );
      datasourceUsername = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.username" );
      dataSourcePassword = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.password" );
      dataSourceUrl = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.url" );

      liquibaseChangeLog = environment.getProperty( "spring.liquibase.change-log" );
      liquibaseDefaultSchema = environment.getProperty( "spring.liquibase.default-schema" );
      log.debug( "Initialisation {} ", datasourceDriverClass );
  }
}
```

2- Inject them in the DB configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = "com.company.product.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "productServiceEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "productServiceTransactionManager", considerNestedRepositories = true )
@EnableTransactionManagement( proxyTargetClass = false )
public class ProductServiceDBConfig {

    private static final String      packageToScan = "com.company.product.models";

    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceProperties productServiceProperties;

    @Bean( name = "productServiceDataSource" )
    public DataSource productServiceDataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName( productServiceProperties.getDatasourceDriverClass() );
       dataSource.setUrl( productServiceProperties.getDataSourceUrl() );
       dataSource.setUsername( productServiceProperties.getDatasourceUsername() );
       dataSource.setPassword( productServiceProperties.getDataSourcePassword() );
       return dataSource;
    }

   @Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter productServiceVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl( false );
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql( true );
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean( name = "productServiceEntityManager" )
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productServiceEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource( productServiceDataSource() );
    emf.setPackagesToScan( packageToScan );
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter( productServiceVendorAdapter() );
    return emf;
}

@Bean( name = "productServiceTransactionManager" )
public PlatformTransactionManager productServiceTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager productTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    productTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( productServiceEntityManager().getObject() );
    return productTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public SpringLiquibase productServiceLiquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource( productServiceDataSource() );
    liquibase.setChangeLog( productServiceProperties.getLiquibaseChangeLog() );
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema( productServiceProperties.getLiquibaseDefaultSchema() );
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```

**userservice :**

1-

```
@Configuration( "userServiceProperties" )
@Getter
@Setter
@PropertySource( value = { "classpath:userservice/application.properties",
    "classpath:userservice/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" } ) //I want properties from properties file source above
public class UserServiceProperties {

    @Autowired //I want `Environment` to contain properties from common properties + files in @PropertySource above
    private Environment environment;

    // ========DATASOURCE PROPERTIES=========
    private String      datasourceDriverClass;
    private String      datasourceUsername;
    private String      dataSourcePassword;
    private String      dataSourceUrl;

    // ========LIQUIBASE PROPERTIES==========
    private String      liquibaseChangeLog;
    private String      liquibaseDefaultSchema;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        datasourceDriverClass = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.driver-class-name" );
        datasourceUsername = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.username" );
        dataSourcePassword = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.password" );
        dataSourceUrl = environment.getProperty( "spring.datasource.url" );

        liquibaseChangeLog = environment.getProperty( "spring.liquibase.change-log" );
        liquibaseDefaultSchema = environment.getProperty( "spring.liquibase.default-schema" );
    }
}
```

2-

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = "com.company.user.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "userServiceEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "userServiceTransactionManager", considerNestedRepositories = true )
@EnableTransactionManagement( proxyTargetClass = false )
public class UserServiceDBConfig {

private static final String         packageToScan = "com.company.user.models";

   @Autowired
   private UserServiceProperties userServiceProperties;

   @Bean( name = "userServiceDataSource" )
   public DataSource userServiceDataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName( userServiceProperties.getDatasourceDriverClass() );
      dataSource.setUrl( userServiceProperties.getDataSourceUrl() );
      dataSource.setUsername( userServiceProperties.getDatasourceUsername() );
      dataSource.setPassword( userServiceProperties.getDataSourcePassword() );
      return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter userServiceVendorAdapter() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl( false );
      hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql( true );
      return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  }

  @Bean( name = "userServiceEntityManager" )
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userServiceEntityManager() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      emf.setDataSource( userServiceDataSource() );
      emf.setPackagesToScan( packageToScan );
      emf.setJpaVendorAdapter( userServiceVendorAdapter() );
      return emf;
  }

  @Bean( name = "userServiceTransactionManager" )
  public PlatformTransactionManager userServiceTransactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      userTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( userServiceEntityManager().getObject() );
      return userTransactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase userServiceLiquibase() {
      SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
      liquibase.setDataSource( userServiceDataSource() );
      liquibase.setChangeLog( userServiceProperties.getLiquibaseChangeLog() );
      liquibase.setDefaultSchema( userServiceProperties.getLiquibaseDefaultSchema() );
      return liquibase;
   }
}
```

The problem is, as I `@Autowired Environment` to get my properties and all properties have same names, some properties always take precedence over other properties. E.g. the property `spring.datasource.url` contains the same value in both services.

I use `Environment` and not `@Value` neither `@ConfigurationProperties` because it gets properties basing on the active profile and that exactly what I want.

My questions are :

- Is it possible to configure `Environment` to get properties from the configuration class where it is injected?
- If not, is there a simple way to achieve what I want to do?
- Should I configure multiple application contexts (one per service) to isolate each `Environment` variable from other? (I am not sure this would work)

Thanks a lot (and sorry for the length of this post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem myself with the suggestion of Andy Wilkinson (@ankinson) on Twitter.

We can't have many properties files with same name. So I had to rename my sub configurations files like this :

```
product.properties
product-dev.properties
product-prod.properties
```

And so on...